# How to update Firebase Data using Constructor class

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I want to update the Name-based from User Input *NIK* then show the data to the field and by pressing the update button it will update the data inside the Database.

I'm using this Constructor Class :

```
import com.google.firebase.database.Exclude
import com.google.firebase.database.IgnoreExtraProperties

@IgnoreExtraProperties
 class DatabaseModelUpdate(
        var nama : String = ""
) {
    @Exclude
   fun toMap(): Map<String, Any?> {
       return mapOf(
               "nama" to this.nama
       )
   }
}
```

and my source code is :

```
 val nama = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editNama).text.toString().trim()
 val model = DatabaseModelUpdate(nama)
 val post = model.toMap()

  var query = reference.orderByKey().equalTo(NIK)
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")

        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                for (userSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                    var keys =  userSnapshot.ref.key.toString()
                        val updates = hashMapOf<String, Any>(
                                "/Users/$keys" to post
                        )
                         userSnapshot.ref.updateChildren(updates)
                      }
                    }
```

My JSON :

[image]

But, after I pressed the Update Button nothing change.

**UPDATE**

Codes:

```
private fun updating() {
        val NIK = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.inputNik).text.toString().trim()
        val nama = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editNama).text.toString().trim()

        var query = reference.orderByChild("nik").equalTo(NIK)
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")

            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (userSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                        var keys =  userSnapshot.ref.key.toString()
                            val updates = hashMapOf<String, Any?>(
                                   "Users/$keys/nama" to nama
                            )
                              dataSnapshot.ref.updateChildren(updates)
```

Database :

[image]

The codes just making a new nodes instead updating the data

**UPDATES 2**
using

> "nama" to nama

database :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the "nama" property of the object which has the key equal to "NIK", you can directly point to that particular property and set the new name as shown in the following lines of code:

```
val query = reference.orderByKey().equalTo(NIK)
val listener = object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        for (ds in dataSnapshot.children) {
            ds.child("nama").getRef().setValue("newNama")
        }
    }

    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()) //Don't ignore potential errors!
    }
}
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener)
```

So there is no need at all to create any additional classes for a simple update.

**Edit:**

You might also consider trying this:

```
for (userSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
    val updates = hashMapOf<String, Any>(
        "nama" to "newNama"
    )
    userSnapshot.ref.updateChildren(updates)
}
```

Comment: actually i made the Constructor Class to update around 10 nodes in one time (it's too tired to "setValue" one by one). But since i can't update it, i tried to debug it one by one and simplified all the codes. Can you help me to discover the problem that i made?

Comment: With this code, you will **not** update a single node, it will update all nodes that satisfy that query. So if there are 10 nodes, then 10 nodes will be updated. Have you tried my solution? Does it work the way you want?

Comment: i did it before i trying to use this code and it was successfull. But, i want to tidying up this 
**update** method by using constructor class, you know repeating 10 same code lines in one method looks bad.

Comment: i'm using this [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#updating_or_deleting_data) as my guide

Comment: Repeating a line of code ten times is not a good practice, but that's **not** the case. There is no need to write that line ten times. One time is enough. Remember that is a bad practice to create extra classes when are actually not needed. I'll update my answer with some new lines of code.

Comment: Check my updated answer. Does it work now?

Comment: does the `post` on `"nama" to post` is refering to this line of code `val model = DatabaseModelUpdate(nama)
 val post = model.toMap()` ? or we can just change it to `"nama" to this.nama`

Comment: update. i just tried with ur codes but instead of updating the existing nodes ("nama"), they adding a new node, and have shared a same name "nama"

Comment: Try using `"nama" to "newNama"` or `"$keys" to post` Does it work now?

Comment: no it not works. lemme update my post to show my current codes and db.

Comment: post has been updated. Please kindly to check

Comment: Change this `"Users/$keys/nama"` to `"nama"`. Does it work?

Comment: no it's not works. they keep making a new nodes, check my post again to see the different.

Comment: Don't use `dataSnapshot.ref.updateChildren(updates)` use `userSnapshot.ref.updateChildren(updates)`. It's **`userSnapshot`**, right?

Comment: aww you right, i missed&forget that. Yep, it works after using `userSnapshot` , thx for ur assist..